# How to get Category Id of current product?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have get the current product category id on product details page. I have used some method like :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(prodId);
$ids = $_product->getCategoryId();
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setId($ids);
```

but its not work as i want.

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount()
        ->addCategoryFilter($cat)
        ->setPageSize($productCount);
```

but its return some times this error

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 719
```

[image]

Comment: `current product category id on product details` means that category from where  are goes to product details page?

Comment: sorry its my mistake. i have set ->addCategoryFilter($cat)  but not fixed result.

Comment: Try $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(array_pop($ids));

Comment: Possible you need another filter $products->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catIds));

Comment: here Category_ids empty @SiarheyUchukhlebau.

Comment: have you assigned category to particular products in admin side?

Comment: yes. but i am open this product from new product slider directly.

Comment: are you need view product on click right?

Comment: i want to just current product category id. so i will get another product and display as May Be Like slider.

Answer (score 11):

Because 1 product can stored in multi categories, so 
when call

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

it will a array.

```
foreach($categoryIds as $id) {
  $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code:

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();        
if(count($categoryIds) ){
    $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);

    echo $_category->getName();
    echo $_category->getId();
}
```

Comment: Products can be attached to multiple categories.                                         In your situation, when you visit a product page referred from a category page, your session has category information. But if you visit directly product page, Magento can not know which category you came from, so it can not show you a specific category, because your product can have multiple categories.

But in your situation, if your products are attached only one category, you can use above code, it shows first category name of product;

Comment: @Kaka It will work if you visit directly product page.I have checked it

Comment: please refer updated question.

Comment: @Arunendra If so, you will get multiple category id if this product attached in multiple category, right ? or you will get single category id ??

Comment: @Arunendra could you pls help me with my own post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

//This will get the info of current product.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); 

$prodID = $product->getId();

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);

$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

foreach($categoryIds as $categoryIds1) {

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds1);

//get all category ID in the current product.

echo $category_id = $_category->getId();

//get all the Category Name of the Current Product.

echo $category_name = $_category->getName();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to obtain the current category on a product page, the easiest way to do that is to get it from the Registry:

```
echo Mage::registry('current_category') ? Mage::registry('current_category')->getName() : 'No category';
```

To get an ID, use:

```
$catid = Mage::registry('current_category') ? Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(prodId);
$ids = $_product->getCategoryId();
var_dump($ids); //this is category id
```

Below code is wrong:

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setId($ids);
```

Comment: Any help with my own post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334 @Prashant Valanda