# Observer Mage::throwException error - status 503 error

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I just want to restrict some of the category of products to purchase with other category products,

Workout :

If customer click **add to cart** using **observer** compare current add-to-cart product category id & already cart products category id, if the current product category id and cart products category id **different** trigger observer & display message like, **You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it**,

and also **vice versa**, if cart has other category of products, if customer try to add restricted category products throw exception like **If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products**

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
    </modules>
    <global> 
        <models>
            <gta_kolupadirestrict>
                <class>Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model</class>
            </gta_kolupadirestrict>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer>   
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cartevent</method>
                    </Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>      
        </events>
    </global>  
</config>
```

my observer :

```
    <?php
class Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer {

    public function cartevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        // Load product
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $prodID = $product->getId();
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);

        // get category id
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

        // check cart
        $cart_qty = (int)Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemQty();

        // check conditiion cart has other products 
        if(in_array(681, $categoryIds) && $cart_qty > 0) {
            Mage::throwException("You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it");
        }

        // check if restricted category of products try to  add to cart
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $_product1 = $item->getProduct();

            $categoryIds1 = $_product1->getCategoryIds();
            if(in_array(681, $categoryIds1)) {
                Mage::throwException("If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products");
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Error :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products";i:1;s:1835:"#0 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/local/Gta/KolupadiRestrict/Model/Observer.php(21): Mage::throwException('If you want Kol...')
#1 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer->cartevent(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer), 'cartevent', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_p...', Array)
#4 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(290): Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_p...', Array)
#5 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(315): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct('5071', Array)
#6 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(133): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->tryaddAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#7 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->indexAction()
#8 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#9 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/abc/public_html/australia/index.php(93): Mage::run('australia', 'website')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:100:"/ajaxcart/index/index/?form_key=MtlJbvKkqPQKCLJR&product=5071&related_product=&qty=1&_=1565155804563";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:9:"australia";}
```

Comment: does your observer work fine? can you please try the below code in your config file.
`<events>
   <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>kolupadirestrict/observer</class>
            <method>cartevent</method>
            <args></args>
          </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>`

Comment: If i update with your code, still both of the category of products adding to add to cart.

Comment: My code is not for logic its just for checking your observer is working or not, so now its working fine then I will check your observer code and let you know if anything.

Comment: Yes, my observer working

Comment: @AasimGoriya Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know wether your conditions work, I leave that up to you. The problem with the error comes - I assume - because the `addProduct()` is not inside a try/catch block.

The default Magento Controller looks like this:

```
\Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction
public function addAction()
{
    /* ... */
    try {
        /* ... */
        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        /* ... */

    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        /* Handle Magento Exception */
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        /* ... */        
    }
}
```

So I would check the extension, because it looks horrible and broken:
https://github.com/roshu1980/add-computers/blob/446b3bea101c239b8e93a39131cb484221bf5437/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php#L151-L156

Answer (score 0):

The line **`$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();`** will give you category IDs in an array format.

So there is no need to use:

```
if($categoryIds->getCategoryIds()=='681' && $cart_qty > 0  )
```

instead, use:

```
if(in_array(681, $categoryIds) && $cart_qty > 0)
```

**Update after checking the observer's code:**

Please try this code:

```
<?php
class Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer {

    public function cartevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $prodID = $product->getId();
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        $cart_qty = (int)Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemQty();
        // foreach ($categoryIds as $category) {


        if(in_array(681, $categoryIds) && $cart_qty > 0) {
            Mage::throwException("If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products");
        }


        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $_product1 = $item->getProduct();
            // $productCategoryId = $item->getCategoryIds();

                // if ($productCategoryId == '681')  //680 category id
                // {
                //  Mage::throwException("Cart has Special Product you can not add another");
                // }
            $categoryIds1 = $_product1->getCategoryIds();
            if(in_array(681, $categoryIds1)) {
                Mage::throwException("If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products");
                break;
            }
        }
        // }
    }     
}
?>
```

Comment: yes,thank you for your help, but both of my condition not working. observer-> https://www.pastiebin.com/5d496e619d3f1  FYI no error.

Comment: Did the first one work for you? What is actually happening after changing the condition shown above?

Comment: Yes, there no error and also logic not appplied

Comment: my exact observer ->  https://paste.ofcode.org/KyEnmJCiuR6r5hmNcdAirR

Comment: @zus, please check my updated answer. This is not tested code and is intended to help you understand the basic idea.

Comment: Cart empty, if i try to add restricted category of products i am getting error -> https://www.pastiebin.com/5d4a59e85e1e3 @Mohit

Comment: That is because you have used **`throwException`**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97133/discussion-between-zus-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Comment: If cart empty observer allow to add restricted category of products to cart, how to do this?

Comment: pls check with my updated post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97141/discussion-between-zus-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Comment: What event should be use before order placed for getting shipping country? @Mohit Kumar Arora